# Torsion spring clips are too small for new LED torsion springs. Help!

Tags: lighting, led

I have purchased 32 LED lights to replace can lighting for my home. Upon trying to install, I realized the wire gauge of the new led torsion springs are thicker than the old can light wire. Because of this the springs will not catch in the existing torsion spring clip. What can I do without incurring a lot of time to replace all the clips? Is there a way to make the existing clips work?

Comment: Some clear, focused, labeled pics of the new cans, old cans, and whatever you're trying to mount the cans to would be very helpful. Feel free to [edit] your post, then just drag the pictures in from your computer, or use the "sun & mountain" button above the text edit box to upload them.